# WSO2 Enterprise Store 1.0.0 : modify login process in Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-es, wso2-identity-server

I am working with Enterprise Store V1.0.0. For now, i use a users store linked to my LDAP  for authentication, which is working fine.
However, all my web applications used a tool for auto login, i mean that a user is automatically logged in the app thanks to this tool. I would like to modify ES to integrate this tool.

After sometimes spent in the code, i think that the entry point should be in the Identity Server. I tried to get the code, modify it and use it with ES, without success. My problem is that i don't know where i can get the good version of the code. I found that the .jar file is generated with the pom.xml in product-es\modules\p2-profile-gen\, but i don't know where is the code i need.

If someone could help, it would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: Are you trying to intercept /store and /publisher login flow and integrate with your tool? If this is the requirement you can find <ES_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/<APP_NAME>/controllers/login.jag where we initiate the login request.

Comment: At the same time I highly recommend you to check the ES2(latest).

Comment: Well, i would like to force the login on /store and /publisher and add my code in the process to use it. It is an authentication system based on Oauth.

Comment: We checked the version 2 of ES but for now, we can't spent time on it. We already made some changes if the version 1 we won't  be able to use as is in the version 2.